# Know how many windows are open for an app at a glance

Tags: window-manager, expose

Is there a way to know at a glance how many windows are open for an app?

In the dock, using El Capitan, a black dot appears under running app icons, but if windows are on top of each other (i.e. Chrome main window, and Chrome Gmail composing new mail popup), there seem to be no way of knowing it without doing an Exposé of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the quickest way is to right click/ctrl-click/hold down on the dock icon. This opens a menu, where you can see all the open windows, even those in full screen, which do not appear in App Exposé. As this menu can grow to be quite long, you want to look for the section with the icon [image: Open window icon] on each line, and a tick next to one of the elements. The number of times this icon appears represents the number of windows of this app currently open.

Here are two examples of this menu for different apps:

**Terminal (2 windows open)**

[image: Terminal right click menu]

**Pages (3 windows open)**

[image: Pages right click menu]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not applicable to all apps (Calendar for example).

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I think that's because Calendar is a single-window app. However, secondary windows, like preferences, do show up on this menu for Calendar.

Comment: But second Calendar window (opened from **Window** menu item, for example "Holidays" etc.) is not present there.

Comment: This is nice to know. I still wish there would be some kind of tool that would show this info in the dock without interaction, though. It could show up to 3 black dots for open windows, instead of only one. Or a dot of a different color if an app has more than one window open.